# File extension naming: .p vs .pkl vs .pickle

Tags: python, naming-conventions, pickle

When reading and writing pickle files, I've noticed that some snippets use `.p` others `.pkl` and some the full `.pickle`.  Is there one most pythonic way of doing this?

My current view is that there is no one right answer, and that any of these will suffice.  In fact, writing a filename of `awesome.pkl` or `awesome.sauce` won't make a difference when running `pickle.load(open(filename, "rb"))`.  This is to say, the file extension is just a convention which doesn't actually affect the underlying data.  Is that right?

Bonus: What if I saved a PNG image as `myimage.jpg`?  What havoc would that create?

Comment: Bonus: it depends what you opened it in after you have saved it. Some programs might be smart enough to detect that its actually a PNG and not a JPEG as the filename would suggest and open it as a PNG image, causing 0 havoc. The way this can be done is that both JPEG and PNG files have a different sequence of bytes at the start. PNG files start with hexadecimal bytes `89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#5DataRep. JPEG files start with the hex bytes `ff d8`, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The **extension** makes **no difference** because "**The Pickle Protocol**" runs every time.

That is to say whenever pickle.dumps or pickle.loads is run the objects are serialized/un-serialized according to the pickle protocol.

(The pickle protocol is a **serialization format**)

The pickle protocol is **python specific**(and there are **several versions**). It's only really designed for a user to re-use data themselves -> if you sent the pickled file to someone else who happened to have a **different version** of pickle/Python then the file might **not load correctly** and you probably can't do anything useful with that pickled file in another language like Java.

So, use what **extensions** you like because the **pickler** will **ignore** them.

**JSON** is another more popular way of serializing data, it can also be used by **other languages** unlike pickle - however it does not cater directly to python and so certain variable types are not understood by it :/

[source](http://www.diveintopython3.net/serializing.html) if you want to read more

EDIT: while you *could* use any name, what **should** you use?

- 1 As mentioned by @Mike Williamson .pickle is used in the pickle docs
- 2 The python standard library **json module** loads files named with a **.json** extension. So it would follow the the **pickle module** would load a **.pickle** extension.
- 3 Using .pickle would also minimise any chance of accidental use by other programs.

**.p** extensions are used by some other programs, most notably MATLAB as the suffix for binary run-time files[sources: [one](https://file.org/extension/p), [two](https://www.filesuffix.com/en/extension/p)]. **Some risk** of conflict

**.pkl** is used by some obscure windows "Migration Wizard Packing List file"[ [source](https://www.filesuffix.com/en/extension/pkl)]. **Incredibly low risk** of conflict.

**.pickle** is only used for python pickling[[source](https://www.filesuffix.com/en/extension/pickle)]. **No risk** of conflict.

Comment: Yes, this is all true, Harry, but I doesn't answer the OP's original question, as I understand it.  The OP has a strong hunch -- correctly -- that there is no *technical* reason to choose one format over another. But he wants to know if there is a more *Pythonic* way.  In other words, what would a style guide recommend? I came here to find a suggestion.  Checking the [pickle docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), they use `.pickle`, but in my experience, I've seen `.p` and `.pkl` more. I could not find anything in PEP talking about this explicitly.  :(