# Any difference between using .pickle/pkl file extension vs no extension when working with pickle files with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I have noticed that all three of these seem to produce the same result (`df` is a pandas dataframe):

```
df.to_pickle('df')
df.to_pickle('df.pkl')
df.to_pickle('df.pickle')
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193963/file-extension-naming-p-vs-pkl-vs-pickle) that there is no difference between .pkl and .pickle but how about using no extension at all like the first one above? Acceptable?

Comment: There is no difference. Add the extention for user friendliness. If you were to transfer a file to me with no extension, I'm left thinking "WTF" because I can't even guess at what it is

Comment: All file extensions are arbitrary although most conform to some convention. Using an extension also facilitates application association for platforms that support that notion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no difference programmatically. The encoding of the file contents will be the same.

That said, there is a *huge* difference when people come to decode the file to try and get something useful back out of it. If you send me a file with no extension then I have absolutely no starting point to guess on how to decode it into something meaningful.

Now, the final thing to say here is that distributing pickle files and having a client read them is a real security threat. One could argue that pickle files would never be distributed, and only used internally in a program itself; in which case, just do yourself and your developers a favour and pick either `.pkl` or `.pickle`